# How to extend a continuous function on the unit circle to an analytic function on the unit disc?

Tags: complex-analysis

Please help me solve this problem:

Let $g(z):\{z: |z|=1\}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function. Show that there is an analytic function $f(z)$ in the $\{z: |z|<1\}$ such that $f$ has continuous extension to $g$.

Answer (score 4):

This is not true. Take $g(z)=\dfrac1z$. Cauchy's integral theorem shows that $g$ can't be extended holomorphically.

Comment: Beat me to it, and with a better example!

Comment: Is it impossible that there are another analytic function which its restriction to a unit circle is $\displaystyle\frac{1}{z}$.

Comment: @WorawitTepsan I don't think you understand. Take the function that is $1/z$ on the unit circle. This function *cannot* be extended. Your claim is not true.

Comment: Yes. Any function $f$ holomorphic on the unit disc, continous on the closure satisfies $$\int_{|z|=1} f(z)\,dz =0$$

Comment: I should have used the same notation as in your question. Clearer now?

Comment: @Potato Can you explain more? Are there some theorem about uniqueness of analytic function (for example: Let $f_1,f_2$ is analytic on a domain. If $f_1(z)=f_2(z)$ for all $z$ in boundary of a ball inside the domain, $f_1=f_2$)?

Comment: @mrf Are you sure? CIF requires the function to be analytic on a domain containing the path.

Comment: @WorawitTepsan This isn't a matter of uniqueness. This is a matter of non-existence. What you stated is not true.

Comment: @WorawitTepsan What is $$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z}\:?$$

Comment: @N.S. A limiting argument easily extends the formula to the boundary of "nice" domains.

Comment: @N.S. Well, at least for the circle, a limiting argument works. It holds in general for Jordan curves (I think) but the proof is difficult. But what mrf is quoting is easy to show.

Comment: @N.S. It's true for $|z|=r$ for any $r<1$ and if $f$ is continuous on $|z|\le 1$, uniform continuity allows us to push out to $|z|=1$. (It is true for any bounded domain with rectifiable boundary, but that's more difficult.)

Comment: @mrf it is $2\pi i$

Comment: @Potato For example in real, I define $f(x)= 0$ on $x=-1,1$. There are many ways to extend f on [-1,1]. Similarly, we know the value on boundary of the unit circle is $1/z$, but it may be impossible to have other functions which on the boundary have the same value of $1/z$.

Comment: @WorawitTepsan I think you are missing the point. There are many functions on the disc equal to $1/z$ on the circle but no *analytic* ones, since the integral along the circle is non-zero.

Comment: Oh!, I get it. Thank you very much for all your help.